# Select result into a type with array

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Having such type created:

```
create type type_student as (student_id numeric, first_name text, subjects text[]);
```

I am trying to create a function that would collect the students:

```
create function collect_students() returns setof type_student
as $function$
declare
   v_result type_student;
   v_student RECORD
begin
   for v_student in select id, first_name, (subject1, subject2, subject3) from students
   loop
      v_result := v_student;
      return next v_result;
   end loop;
end;
$function$ language plpgsql;
```

Where id, first_name, subject1, subject2, subject3 are columns in the students table.

I am getting casting errors connected with **subjects** value in the **type_student** type. Is there a way to do it without assigning each element of the array individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subjects` is declared as an array of text. Your SELECT returns a record type column, not an array.

The following should work:

```
select id, first_name, array[subject1, subject2, subject3] from students
```

---

However, you don't need a type, nor a FOR loop, nor PL/pgSQL for this:

```
create function collect_students() 
  returns table (student_id numeric, first_name text, subjects text[])
as $function$
  select id, first_name, array[subject1, subject2, subject3]
  from students
$function$ 
language sql;
```

If you do want to use PL/pgSQL you still don't need a (slow) FOR loop. A simple `return query select ...;` will do.